# Should statistics be collected on a UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX in Teradata?

Tags: teradata

A long time ago, I was told that I should not collect statistics on on a Teradata UPI, but I never understood the reason.  It may have been related to the version we were running at that time.  It also may have been that a UPI doesn't need stats so collecting them is a waste of time.

My question is: should I continue that practice now that we are using TD 13.10 (and soon moving to TD 14)?  If so, does the size of the table make a difference, such as a 1000-row AVT table versus a 100-million row detail table, both having a single-column UPI widely used by join operations?

Any specific references to Teradata documentation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should collect UPI stats for very small tables, for big tables it depends on the usage pattern: If it's only for joins you don't need it, because the optimizer already knows about uniqueness. Only when you have WHERE-conditions on that column beside equality stats might be neccessary, but then SAMPLE STATS are ok.

For each release there's an "official" recommendation by Carrie Ballinger, e.g.

http://developer.teradata.com/blog/carrie/2012/04/teradata-13-10-statistics-collection-recommendations

Comment: Is there any reason NOT to collect stats on a UPI of any size or is it only that collecting on a big table is a waste of time?  If so, is there a rule of thumb to define "big table"?  Is it a function of the number of amps on the system?

Comment: No, the only reason is resources, COU/IO/time. The "official" definition of small is "< 100 rows/AMP", i usually start sampling for approx. "> 100,000/AMP". Small|large|big|real big|whatever depends on your defintion, but it's always based on rows/AMP.